# Can a jewel that's an arcane focus be put on a rod and still count as one?

Tags: dnd-5e, spellcasting-focus

What an arcane focus can be is listed in the Player's Handbook. If we say the player has a blue jewel and this is his arcane focus and the player put this jewel on a simple rod (not magic - any branch from a tree as example) will this combined thing be a valid arcane focus, or not?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### Strictly speaking, the caster has to hold the arcane focus.

The spellcasting focus rules say (emphasis mine):

> A spellcaster must have a hand free to access a spell’s material components — **or to hold a spellcasting focus** — but it can be the same hand that he or she uses to perform somatic components.

Hence, if the jewel is put on the top of a rod and the latter is held by the caster, the jewel cannot work as an arcane focus.

#### The DM may (and should?) rule otherwise

Honestly, I do not see any issues coming from still treating the jewel as a *working* arcane focus: the hand of the caster is still occupied as requested by the rules.

Another way is to rule that the rod with the jewel works as an arcane focus: this depends on the player, if they desire that the jewel (and not the rod) *is* the arcane focus.

As a DM, I would allow it since I consider this as a nice touch of personalization of the character.

Comment: "if the jewel is put on the top of a rod and the latter is held by the caster, the jewel cannot work as an arcane focus". What if the jewel is placed on a glove, and the caster is holding the glove? I'd argue the caster is holding the jewel in both cases, albeit not directly.

Comment: @Vaelus it depends if the jewel is on the palm of the glove (i.e. between the fingers) or not (on the back of the hand).

Comment: @Vaelus wait a minute: wearing or holding the glove?

Comment: Wearing, to be specific, but I'd say wearing a glove is also holding a glove, even if it's not common in everday speech.

Comment: @Vaelus no, that's different. In case of wearing, the above comment of mine answers to your observation, in case of holding it depends: if you're holding the glove by a finger, you're not holding the jewel, if you're holding the whole glove and the jewel is between your fingers, then you're holding also the focus.

Comment: @Vaelus The problem with interpreting "wearing" as "holding" for this rule applied to a glove with mounted focus, is you get to use the focus *and* have a free hand, which would appear to be trying to find a loophole in the rules. It would diminish the relative benefits of caster/warrior types who get to have weapons or shields as spell foci. Perhaps worth a separate question, as the whole "how are you juggling your equipment to do X?" is important to some tables, and a drag at others.

Answer (score 12):

The DM can and should make decisions like this, but there seems to be no reason to deny it. An arcane focus can be "an orb, a crystal, a rod, a specially constructed staff, a wand-like length of wood, or some similar item". The only real rule is that you have to have a hand free to manipulate the focus when casting with it.

I guess my question would be: Why not? Sticking a crystal on top of a stick to make it a rod doesn't really change anything about the focus or its use. Is it giving the player an advantage of some kind, or is it just a bit of descriptive text?  If it's the latter, what's the point of litigating it?

It might be worth a crafting check or some such thing, but this sounds a lot like "I decided I want my character to look like *this* instead of *that*", which really should not be something the DM is trying to prevent.

Comment: ... especially since a rod is one of the allowed alternatives for a spellcasting focus anyway.  The rod with a crystal stuck on the end might not be *the same* focus as the crystal itself, but I see no particular reason why it shouldn't be allowed as *a* focus.